# SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Ogretmenler' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

i am getting this error
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Ogretmenler' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)

DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection

what should i do?

here is my code

[HttpGet]

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> value = (from Ders in _db.Dersler.ToList()
                                      select new SelectListItem
                                      {
                                          Text = Ders.DersName,
                                          Value = Ders.Id.ToString()
                                      }).ToList();
        ViewBag.v1 = value;


        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Ogretmen obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Ogretmenler.Add(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(obj);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your code of the Create view ?

Comment: There are many many questions on this error. Please find one that covers your case.

Comment: @QingGuo <div class="mb-3">
   <h6>Öğretmen Seçiniz</h6>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(Ogretmen=>Ogretmen.Id,new SelectList(ViewBag.v1,"Value","Text"))
  </div>

Comment: "Html.DropDownListFor(Ogretmen=>Ogretmen.Id" From  your code, you add the Id, as jkrat said, "Make sure the object you add to the db does not have a value for the ID field.", so you don't need  to add Id.

Answer (score 1):

The exception 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF' is thrown when you attempt to insert a value in the Identity Column.

Either:

- Make sure the object you add to the db does not have a value for the ID field.

or

- Turn on Identity insert if you want to be able to insert the ID manually with 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT Ogretmenler ON'.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because key field for my table has attributes
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Deleted Database generated and no problem anymore